# How to calculate the number of times a value occurs for different unique IDs in R?

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the number of times a zero and one occurs for each ID. I have a single column with >500 unique IDs and each ID has a different number of times zeroes and ones occur. Thanks!

I am doing this in R using for loops

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example, for example a small data frame that demonstrates your starting data and what type of output you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: How can you have a singe column of ID's as well as zeros.. ^ Please provide your data.

Comment: ID Treatment
100a002 1
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 1
100a002 1
100a002 1
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 0
100a002 1
100a002 1
100a002 1
100a002 1
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 0
100a003 1
100a003 1
100a003 1
100a003 1
100a003 1
100a003 1

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like this could help you:

```
#Example dataframe
dummy=data.frame(ID=c(10101,11110101,11111))

#Separate every character in ID column
Sepdummy=strsplit(as.character(dummy$ID), split="")

#Count how many times a value is repeated
dummy$Zeroes=unlist(lapply(Sepdummy, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)==0)))
dummy$Ones=unlist(lapply(Sepdummy, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)==1)))
```

Output looks like:

```
ID  Zeroes  Ones
10101   2   3
11110101    2   6
11111   0   5
```

The above will not work if your ID's aren't numeric. For that you can just use `str_count()` from `stringr` package (as pointed elsewhere in this post):

```
library(stringr)
#Example dataframe
dummy=data.frame(ID=c(10101,11110101,11111,"asd0110001df"))

#Count using str_count and add the results to the original dummy dataframe, so the results are all viewed in the same table.
dummy$Zeroes=str_count(dummy$ID, "0")
dummy$Ones=str_count(dummy$ID, "1")
```

Comment: My IDs are not strictly numeric. So you'd suggest to use the second option with the stringr package? Can you explain your first line of code?

Comment: @MatthewFuirst Yes, if that's the case then I suggest the second option using stringr. The first line would be `dummy=data.frame(ID=c(10101,11110101,11111,"asd0110001df"))`. I'm just trying to create a small example using a dataframe as in your original post you didn't include an example.

Answer (score 2):

Within the library **stringr**, you have the function **str_count()** which enable to count the number of occurences of a character in a string.

```
library(stringr)

str_count("abracadabra", "a")         # return 5
str_count("0010110", "0")             # return 4
str_count("001d021", "0|1")           # return 5
str_count(c("001", "123", "salut"))   # return (3, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative guess, maybe your data frame looks like this?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
data.df <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)), value=rbinom(20,1,.5))

count.df <- data.df%>%group_by(id)%>%summarize(ones=sum(value==1),zeros=sum(value==0))%>%ungroup()%>%as.data.frame
```

Answer (score 1):

With the vector you gave above:

Transform the vect to a viable dataframe:

```
data=data.frame(matrix(vect,,2,byrow=T))
with(data,table(ID,Treatment))
         Treatment
ID         0  1
  100a002 16  8
  100a003 18  6
```

data:

```
data=read.table(text=" ID Treatment 
                100a002 1 
                100a002 0 
                100a002 0
                100a002 0 
                100a002 1 
                100a002 1 
                100a002 1 
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0 
                100a002 0 
                100a002 0
                100a002 0 
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 0
                100a002 1 
                100a002 1 
                100a002 1
                100a002 1
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 0
                100a003 1
                100a003 1
                100a003 1
                100a003 1 
                100a003 1
                100a003 1",h=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Efficient way to do it

```
dummy<- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)), value=rbinom(20,1,.5))
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)[, list(count_of_one = length(which(value==1)),count_of_zeroes = length(which(value==0))), by = id]
```

output

```
   id      count_of_one   count_of_zeroes
1:  1            5               5
2:  2            6               4
```